# GameKit for apps other than games

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

This might seem like a dumb question, but can GameKit be used for apps other than games? That is, will Apple approve an app that uses GameKit for bluetooth purposes but doesn't use them for games? Or will they reject it based on "misuse of hardware/software" or whatever that rule is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Apple's "Game Kit Programming Guide":

> Peer-to-peer connectivity allows your game to create an ad-hoc Bluetooth or local wireless network between multiple iOS-based devices. Although designed with games in mind, **this network is useful for any type of data exchange among users of your application**. For example, an application could use peer-to-peer connectivity to share electronic business cards or other data.

This clearly answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GameKit can be used for things other than games, in fact, in some situations it is better than using other communication frameworks, as it is ridiculously simply to create a local network connection between two devices, and you can send any data you wish over the connection you create.